# How to animate splines using animation node

Tags: splines

How to animate [image: outline text]linear spline (Outline) on a text like its been drawn from start to end of the word using animation nodes,

Comment: did you ever try googling this? there are some good tutorials out there...and they are easy to find. And next question: do you have experience with AN?

Comment: Yeah Mr. Chris, Bit familar with animation node..it will be kind of you to aid me or guide me as how i can accomplish the above result,,, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok, let's see how familiar you are: here is my guide for you:

Create a text, convert to curve.
Create animation node tree, get curve from object node -> loop over splines -> animate it with trim spline node and use curve object output to show them.

UPDATE:

The "trick" is to use a spline list:

[image]

Comment: I did follow your node settings, but only one letter gets outline or spline, rest of the letters are blank.. By the way I am using 2.79 and animation node 2.0

Comment: please do not edit my answer to show me what you did. This is NOT part of an answer. Edit your question for this. Or include a picture via link in your comment. Thank you. I updated my answer. Hopefully you got it now.